# Can i change the default settings files used by visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In general, is there a way to change the default parameters of the various json (and other) config files used by Visual Studio (2017).

My specific case is when working on a cmake project, I would like the CMakeSettings.json to have the vcpkg toolchain parameter set automatically, whenever I open or creates a new cmake project.